# changing image on UIImageView before segue

Tags: ios, uiimageview, segue

I'm making a game that asks the user a series of questions and each time the user gets it right, a UIImageView will change its image. The code I have works except when the game reaches the last question, I call for a segue onto another view controller.... I still want the image to change before it segues but it will not...

Comment: How are you trying to do this? From a UX point of view, if you're making it so that the image changes and then the view controller pops right afterward, your users might find that annoying. You should change the image and give them time to react, and give them a button or something to segue to the next view controller.

Comment: Expanding on the above, where are you setting the image? In prepareForSegue?